# Parameters for anonymous function in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-navigation

In the React Navigation [documentation for Header Buttons](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons), there is a code that creates a function that updates the "count" state.

`const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);`

`<Button onPress={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)} title="Update count" />`

[demo link from documentation](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=header%20interaction&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.3.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.3.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.6.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.2.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fheader-interaction.js)

I assume that the variable `c` is supposed to be the current count in the anonymous function that is created for onPress. However there is no reference to `c` elsewhere in the code.

Where is the value of `c` coming from and how is it being linked to `count` state?

Comment: **c** is the previous state(to be more precise, the current one) of the variable(count). You can call it whatever you want. To understand, `setCount((thisCount) => thisCount + 1)`

Comment: Thank you, I also found it mentioned in the useState documentation.

Comment: You're passing a function to setCount, which is a function returned by setState, which is where you would find the logic for how the passed function is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest and most friendly explanation would be to compare it with `Array#map` function. `Arrat#map` is a *higher-order function*  - it means that it takes other function as the argument/parameter.

```
[1, 2].map((item) => item + 1); // [2, 3]
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the callback function
```

The same situation with the *setState* function (in your example - `setCount`) - it **takes** a function as argument. A function that works the same as the function passed above to the `Array#map`, with that difference that in `Arrat#map` the `item` parameter is the currently iterated element of the array, but in the state setter function, `item` (or `c` in your case) will stand as the current value of the state (of `count` in your case).

```
setCount((c) => c + 1);
  //     ^^^ current value of `count`
```

Then, `React` simply invokes the function you have passed with current state value. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The setState return setter function from useState [automatically passes the previous value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of the state to a function passed to setState.

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a function to a state updater like you're doing here, React invokes that function with the current value.

`c` is being passed in by React. (It's just a regular function parameter so you can name it whatever you want.)